# Query database by textbox

Tags: c#

I need to query my database for found person by keyin name " space " surname, name and surname are both in different column in the same table.

When user key in in textbox, query must be some thing like:

```
string valueToSearch = MyTextBox.Text.ToString();
searchUserData(valueToSearch);

public void searchUserData(string valueToSearch)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = MyConstring;

    string searchQuery = "SELECT [NDM],[Prenom],[Nom],[Sex],[DateNaiss],[Adresse],[Tel]  FROM [Lab062016].[dbo].[LabPatients] WHERE Nom LIKE '%" + valueToSearch + "%' OR Prenom LIKE '%" + valueToSearch + "%' ";

    SqlCommand cmande = new SqlCommand(searchQuery.ToString(), conn);

    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable table;
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmande);
    table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Comment: Beware of [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Watch your spelling.  Programming is not forgiving this way.